# How can I automatically select current date in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, date-range

I was wondering how to have auto date selection. Here is the code.
In the date range selector, I want the second row to be current date meaning it should reflect the latest date every time the page is loaded.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>


<script>
var today = new Date();
var dd = today.getDate();
var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!
var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
 if(dd<10){
        dd='0'+dd
    } 
    if(mm<10){
        mm='0'+mm
    } 
today = yyyy+'-'+mm+'-'+dd;
document.getElementById("datefield").setAttribute("max", today);
function getdate() {
var date1=new Date();
document.getElementById("start2").value = new Date()
document.getElementById("start1").value=date1;
}
function onLoad() {
 var y = document.getElementById("myDIV");
 y.style.display = "none";
}
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("mySelect").value;
   var y = document.getElementById("myDIV");
 
  if (x === "Momentum") {
     y.style.display = "block";
    
  } 
else {
     y.style.display = "none";
    
  }
}
 
</script>
      

<script>

var date = new Date();
var today = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate());
var optComponent = {
  format: 'mm-dd-yyyy',
  container: '#datePicker',
  orientation: 'auto top',
  todayHighlight: true,
  autoclose: true
};
// COMPONENT
$('#datePicker').datepicker(optComponent);
$('#datePicker').datepicker('setDate', today);


</script>
<style>
body  {
  background-image: url("/static/images/photo2.jpg");
    
    
  
height: 100%; 
  /* Center and scale the image nicely */
  background-position: full;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
         label {
    width:180px;
    clear:left;
    text-align:right;
    padding-right:10px;
}
input, label {
    float:left;
}
.custom1{
width:14%;
display:inline-block;
float: left;
clear:None;
}
.custom2{
width:17%;
display:inline-block;
float: left;
clear:None;
margin-top:1.5%;
}
.custom3{
position:absolute;
left: 0%; 
margin-top:40%;
}
</style>




   </head>
   
    
   <body onload="onLoad()">


      <form method="post" action="/BacktestAnalysis">
         
    


        



    
        <div class="custom1"> 


        <p>Strategy list </p> 

<select id="mySelect" onchange="myFunction()">

<option enabled selected value> -- select an option -- </option>
<option value="Momentum">Momentum</option>

  
</select>


<div id="myDIV">
<br> </br>
         <label for="number">Moving average window</label> <br> </br>
         <input type="number" name="ma" value=13>  <br> </br>
         

</div>









         
         








         
</div>
        







<div class="custom1">

  <p>Rebalance period</p> 

<select name="myDropDown2">
  
  
  <option value='BM'> Monthly</option>
  
  
</select>

</div>





        
         







<div class="custom2"> 

        
<label for="start">Date Range:</label>

<input type="date" id="start" name="start"
       min="1940/02/27" value="2005-01-01"> 




<input type="date" id="start" name="datePicker"
       min="2005-01-01" value=""> 


    


</div>


  

         
        
        
       
        
         

 <div class="custom3">       


 <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="ok"/>  


</div>

         
      </form>


 
   </body>


    
</html>
```

Comment: Please revise your post to put the code in a proper snippet demo and remove the huge whitespace gaps.

Answer (score 0):

What I understand that you want to change the value of the second date input to be the current date.

Here is your element (I added a class for it to get it later with it)

```
        <input type="date" id="start" name="datePicker" min="2005-01-01" value="" class="secondDate">
```

*i added a class for it.

to change the display date we need to change the value of that input. after that we will get the current date from Date class and assign the new date to our element.
like this :

```
let ele = document.querySelector(".secondDate");
var today = new Date();
var d = String(today.getDate() - 1).padStart(2, '0');
var m = String(today.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0');
var y = today.getFullYear();
ele.value = y + "-" + m + "-" + d;
```

^ this code should be inside your script tag. but one thing to always remember your scripts code should always come after the body tag. because you cant change element that does not exists yet!